# How to handle the (oracle) db connection with multiple schema using single knex connection?

Tags: node.js, oracle, knex.js, node-oracledb

I am using `knex` ,  `oracle 19c` is my database.
i have two schema,
SCHEMA1 and SCHEMA2, get the SCHEMA1  connection and execute the query into SCHEMA2.
i need to access multiple schema using single connection (single transaction scope).
so tired [withSchema](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-withSchema) method.I get the query like

> select * from "SCHEMA2"."TABLE1"

while execute this query using knex connection it throws an error

> Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

i manually removed `"` from schema and execute the query that works fine.

How to handle this?

Note: For pg database that works fine with `"`.

Comment: Maybe you need additional Grants. 
Connect as SCHEMA2 and execute: "grant select on TABLE1 to SCHEMA1;"

Comment: i have the access from both the schema. I can get the SCHEMA1 table's result from SCHEMA2 using plsql developer tool.

Comment: @bernhard.weingartner This is not Grants issue. this may be a `""` issue,(`"SCHEMA1"`)

Comment: Oracle consider "SCHEMA1" as table name, so that it throws an error "Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.".How to handle this

Comment: Create a view, and use that in the app?  Use [`currentSchema`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propconncurrentschema)?

Comment: @Christopher Jones to get the data from multiple schema we can create a view and use it. But if we want to make an insert  how to do that?

Comment: My scenario is  make the new insert in schema1 table and get the id and make new insert into schema2 table. If insert failed in schema2 table insert, need to rollback schema1 table insert.